# Eclipse: Incompatible JVM: Version 1.8.0_281 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required

Tags: eclipse

I installed Eclipse Java 2020-12 today and was able to use it immediately after installing. However, when I restarted the IDE to reload a dependency, Eclipse would not start. Instead, it gave me the error

> Incompatible JVM: Version 1.8.0_281 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required."

I have tried editing eclipse.ini to change "Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion" from 11 to 1.8, but then I get a different error which sends me to a log file filled with errors of the form

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse....

At the time of writing, I am using the most recent versions of both Eclipse and the JDK. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Changing that system property doesn't change the fact that it does indeed require Java 11 or newer. So, what does the .ini file point to for its JVM? Or are you setting it some other way?

Comment: You must use Java 11 or later to run Eclipse 2020-12 (but you can still develop programs for earlier versions of Java).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by adding the following line to my eclipse.ini file (in the Eclipse installation directory)

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\javaw.exe

before the existing line

-vmargs

Comment: Doesn't work for me.